# What happens in SQL merge if the join condition has two columns which are not unique and how to solve it?

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I use the follwing query. I used distinct clause to get unique values but I am getting ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables as col1 and col2 are not unique

```
merge into TargetTable t
using (
       select distinct s.col1, s.col2, s.col3 
       from SourceTable s
) st on st.col1 = t.col1 and st.col2 = t.col2
when matched then update
     set t.col3 = st.col3
```

Sample Data:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
----------------------
Cust1   Bank1   Addr1
Cust2   Bank2   Addr2
Cust3   Bank3   Addr3
Cust2   Bank1   Addr4
Cust3   Bank1   Addr5
Cust1   Bank2   Addr6
Cust3   Bank1   Addr7
Cust2   Bank1   Addr8
Cust1   Bank3   Addr9
```

Comment: can you provide your table sturcute - the error means you've duplicate data

Comment: The table is in PCI environment so I cant put the actual data but the col1 and col2 are two codes that identifies the customer and col3 is the updated value for the customer. Combination of col1,col2 and col3 is distinct but the col1 and col2 are not unique on their own.

Comment: you don't need to put actual data, but dummy data is also helpful for understanding the problem - so it's better if you provider some dummy data

Comment: For  `(Cust2,Bank1)` - how do you decide if the target table's col3 should be updated to Addr4 or Addr8?

Comment: @KaushikNayak I think that is the reason why I am getting this error. I queried my tables and there are multiple values for a combination of (col1,col2). There are upto 3 values of col3 for a pair of col1,col2.

Comment: The issue was ,as pointed out by KaushikNakyak, the multiple matches for the join condition. Once i took a singular value for the join condition, the query worked. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

As your error means you've some duplicate data so for removing this you can use aggregation of col3 and then try like below:

```
merge into TargetTable T
using (
       select S.col1,S.col2,max(S.col3) as col3
       from SourceTable S group by S.col1,S.col2
) ST on ST.col1 = t.col1 and ST.col2 = T.col2
when matched then update set T.col3 = ST.col3
```